# MySQL statement if number is less than php variable

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any possibility to make an MySQL statement to select the number if it is less than some value?
Lets say I have a php variable:
myvar = 123;

And I have some records in database:
120
125
129
121

I want to take all possible database records, where myvar and record difference is less than 5.
In this example, it would take 120, 125 and 121.
Is it possible to do this? If yes, maybe someone could help me out how?

Comment: please share us code what you have tried yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mysql's [**BETWEEN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `record` BETWEEN {$myvar}-5 AND {$myvar}+5";
```

[**See mysql demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79e9d/1)

*Note:* `BETWEEN` will match records between `min` and `max`, *including* `min` and `max`. Keep this in mind when developing the logic for your application.

Comment: Brief, easy and understandable for novice like me! Thanks @Mark M!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `field` <= your_variable+5
  AND `field` >= your_variable-5
```

[<kbd>**Check SQL Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc98e/1)

Comment: @bereal I mean 123 is stored in user variable I give just example to write constant here

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `field_name` BETWEEN (123-4) AND (123+4)


In generalized form as below.
$myvar = 123;
$difference = 5;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
        WHERE `field_name` BETWEEN ($myvar - $difference +1) AND ($myvar + $difference -1)";
```

Explanation:
->As mentioned difference should less than 5 .NOT LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 5.

Lets' Say the required nos are x.

123-x < 5 => 118 < x => 119,120,121,122,123
x-123 > 5 => x > 128 => 127,126,125,124,123

Hence x could be 119 to 127.

=>(123-5)+1 < x < (123+5)-1

Hope this explanation clarifies the sql i wrote above.

Comment if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution, but I got an easier one. +1